# Changing a If button press to a if button not pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know this is a very stupid question and very easy for most people to answer, but this is what I have so far:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        rotation += speed * Time.deltaTime; 
    }
```

I know that is is something to do with a "!" but not sure where to put it.

And i would also like to know how to put it into this context:

```
        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) && ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))))
    {
        if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 0){
        rotation += speed * Time.deltaTime;     
       }
    }
```

And I would like to check that both of them are not pressed.

Comment: `if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))` . See also [logical negation operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators)

Comment: Looks like you should go through some very basic c# tutorials before jumping into Unity .....

Comment: Haha yes probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with unity but assuming function names and enums are correct then this should trigger when it's not the right or left arrow that is pressed (in your example you used `RightArrow` twice).

Your IDE should let you know about syntax errors though.

```
if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
  if (transform.eulerAngles.z < 0) {
    rotation += speed * Time.deltaTime;     
  }
}
```

Comment: Your right I did. Oops. Maybe that was why I was getting errors.

Comment: The errors you get should provide you with enough information to solve it yourself. If those are unclear for you then a suggest to do a introduction course to c# first.

Answer (score 2):

I need more information about the question you want to ask.
Based on the information you've provided so far, my advice is:

```
if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
{
    rotation += speed * Time.deltaTime; 
}
```